# What is a "Class hierarchy:

Tags: oop, hierarchy

A client of mine asked me to create a Class Hierarchy for Automating HTML form generation , Validation , Submission and Processing.

I am unclear what this means.

Would it just be the route of how this process is done ?

If some one could you me a link to a tutorial that could be great.

Answer (score 2):

A class hierarchy usually means an inheritance hierarchy.

The client most probably meant a "class design" or a "class diagram".

[Wikipedia on Object Oriented Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design)

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial's on how to build one ?

Comment: There are many many approaches. Most common is the use of UML, a visual language to draw class diagrams (and others). There are a lot of tools around. You can't learn UML and OO design in a few hours.

Comment: @Oliver - you learn that in school. Not that I'm trying to be mean, this is a complex subject that constitutes the bulk of a undergrad CS curriculum. It can't be glossed over with a tutorial as all you'll get is how to make pretty pictures.

Answer (score 1):

He wants you to define a diagram where you will explain how the classes will carry out HTML form generation, validation, submission and processing, by acting together.

This could be done in [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) for instance, just do a brief search on Google images to get a quick understanding of what this means; [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020165783X) helps me a lot when I have to do such things, you can find chapter samples online.

Answer (score 1):

A class can extends another class. When you have a several inheritance ( extends ) bounds beetween class, you can call that class hiearchie.

http://img5.yfrog.com/i/image1y.gif "real world exemple of class hierachie

Answer (score 0):

I think he needs some class diagram where inheritance chain will be shown

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial's on how to build one ?

Answer (score 0):

Perheps the client means a set of classes that handles Form generation, Validation, Submission and Processing?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the inheritance chain of your classes (you code in C++ or C#) that you are going to use to create these forms automatically in webpages etc...